# Stop Moving Service carousel items on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

New JS Bie
Dear All i have a wordpress theme website http://www.kreativestudio.ca in which service carousel items are moving horizontally the code which are making the item move is:

```
(function (){
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        var el = jQuery(".serv_corusel a.bx-next");
        setInterval(function(){
            el.trigger('click');
        },4000);
    });
})();
```

I want a help, I have a v little knowledge of javascript what I need is that on moves hover it gets stoped and when mouse gets over it again start moving.

Regards Tapos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
(function (){
    jQuery(document).ready(function movecar(){
    var el = jQuery(".serv_corusel a.bx-next");
    var timer = setInterval(function(){el.trigger('click');
    },2000);

    jQuery(".serv_corusel").hover(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    },function(){
    timer = setInterval(function(){el.trigger('click');
    },2000);});
    });
 })();
```